# Windows Server not installing audio drivers properly

Tags: drivers, audio, windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install a dummy sound card on a Windows Server machine (in Amazon EC2 cloud) in order for one of my application to work.

I'm trying to accomplish that with Virtual Audio Cable and REAUDIO3. Both tools managed to install a new device on my Windows XP machine, but on Windows Server, no new devices appear.

Windows Audio and Plug and Play services are Started and Automatic.

ANY ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can sometimes get legacy drivers to work by setting the installer's compatibility to XP SP3.  Right-click the driver's setup.exe and choose properties.  Go to the compatibility tab and change it to Windows XP SP3.  Run the install as Administrator (right-click, run as Administrator).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: version 3 doesn't work in windows 2008 server.

There are two versions of Virtual Audio Cable.  Version 4 does not support RDP but version 3 supposedly does. Have you tried version 3?

http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac3.htm

Comment: re: v3. Windows 2008 64 bit will reject the v3 32 bit drivers.